# Add view count to webpage from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a view count feature for a webpage. To do this, I created a new property and generated a tracking id from [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=1#/).

Is there a way I can use the page vists data from there and display it on the same page that I am tracking?

Answer (score 1):

**You can, but since GA APIs are authenticated, you will need to handle that authentication one way or another**.

You have basically 3 options:

- **User doing OAuth**: by default you would need to implement the OAuth flow like the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is doing, which is obviously not adequate if the counter is meant to be public, as visitors won't have the appropriate GA permissions to get data from that property
- **Pre generated access token**: you can generate the `access token` manually, and use that token to make the requests:
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth-options

> serverAuth.access_token    Type:  string
>
> If you already have a valid access token, you can pass it to the
>   authorize method directly and the user will not be prompted to
>   authorize. For details on how to retrieve an access token, see the
>   OAuth 2.0 documentation.

- **Middleware**: you can use a tool to pull data from the GA API and then query data from that tool. For instance you can:

  1. [Use the GA add-on to pull your data to a Google Sheet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)
  2. Import that data into another Google Sheet with [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
  3. [Publish the Google Sheet from 2](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) so it's publicly readable via API (for instance as CSV). You will be provided with a URL that looks like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/{some-uid}/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv`
  4. Fetch data from that URL from the website (eg [with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409920/loading-a-csv-file-using-jquery-get-returns-the-header-but-no-data))

Note: you probably don't have to do step 2 if you're careful, and can publish as CSV your sheet from steo 1 directly: since it's a CSV export, people cannot get to the original spreadsheet so no security risk. But just to be on the safe side (eg you could publish the whole spreadsheet by mistake), I would do step 2.

As for which middleware you want to use, there's probably an infinite number of options :)